# How to index table in Matlab based on regular expressions for variable headers?

Tags: matlab, matlab-table

I am attempting to read in a CSV file that has data in multiple columns that are not applicable for the program I am attempting to run. I'd only like to read from the table from columns that contain 'CX'. Is there a way to do this in a table? Effectively, I am trying to index through the table using a regular expression.

Comment: Are you trying to filter based on the contents of the columns or the names of the columns? Can you share an example?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already have loaded the CSV as table, and want to select based on column variable name, you can use `contains`:

```
CX_1 = rand(10,1);
CX_2 = rand(10,1);
CY_1 = rand(10,1);

T = table(CX_1, CY_1, CX_2)

VarNames = T.Properties.VariableNames;
VarsToKeep = contains(VarNames, 'CX');
T_cx = T(:, VarsToKeep)
```

If you want to match with a regular expression, you can also use the following:

```
VarsToKeep = ~cellfun(@isempty, regexp(VarNames, 'CX'));
T_cx = T(:, VarsToKeep)
```